# How can I fix this quicksort partition in python? (dealing with Numpy arrays)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've been working on this quicksort partition for several days and still can't fix it. I've tried debugging it with prints to see how partitions evolve when called by the main quicksort but still can't figure out how to fix it.
Showing the doctest to give context, apologies if it isn't relevant.

It works on some examples but not in others and can't figure out why.
Any insight and help much appreciated.

```
def partition (s, cmp):
>>> import generate
>>> import numpy
>>> import element
>>> def cmp (x,y):
...    if x == y:
...       return 0
...    elif x < y:
...       return -1
...    else:
...       return 1
>>> t = numpy.array([element.Element(i) for i in [3, -8, 2 , -2, 3, 7, 9, 1, -1, 7]])
>>> p = {'left':0,'right':len(t)-1,'data':t}
>>> p1,p2 = partition(p,cmp)
>>> p1['data'][p1['left']:p1['right']+1]
array([-8, 2, -2, 3, -1, 1], dtype=object)
>>> p2['data'][p2['left']:p2['right']+1]
array([9, 7, 7], dtype=object)
"""
    a = s["data"]   #whole array
    lp = s["left"]+1  #left pointer
    rp = s["right"]    #right pointer
    pivot = a[lp-1]    #pivot is element of index lp=0 in slice
    while lp <= rp:
        if cmp(a[lp], pivot) <= 0:  #lp is already on the correct side since it's <= to pivot
            a[lp-1] = a[lp]
            lp += 1   #moving towards center
        else:
            a[lp], a[rp] = a[rp], a[lp] #taking advantage of python's easy swap
            rp -= 1     #moving towards center
    a[rp] = pivot   #replacing pivot in the end
    lslice = {"data" : a, "left" : s["left"], "right" : rp-1}   #<pivot
    rslice = {"data" : a, "left" : rp+1, "right" : s["right"]}  #>pivot
    return (lslice,rslice)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem, rookie mistake. It didn't come from the program in itself but from the test definition,

```
>>> p0 = {'left':0,'right':len(t)-1,'data':t1}
```

had to be

```
>>> p0 = {'left':0,'right':len(t1)-1,'data':t1}
```